# PHPUnit test in Eclipse 4.2 using Makegood is not running

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, makegood

I have PHPUnit installed using composer and everything works as expected.
I can run tests and I get the expected output.

This is my composer.json

```
...
"require-dev": 
{
  "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*",
  "piece/stagehand-testrunner": ">=3.6.1" 
},
...
```

I then installed MakeGood 2.5 using the marketplace,

- Under Makegood > General I selected the preload script
- The file pattern I use is 'test.php$'
- Under Makegood > PHPUnit I have given the path to the configuration file.
- Under PHP Include Path > Libraries I have added the path to composer/vendor.

But when I select a test file and I right click and select 'Run Tests' the bootstrap file is never called.
Even if I manually add `'require_once "vendor/autoload.php";'` to the file, the test is not actually run.

My *guess* is that the script is not started properly somehow.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? How can I run my tests from within Eclipse using MakeGood?

Thanks

FFMG

Comment: Just to reply to my own comment, get the latest versions of MakeGood and Eclipse and everything will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

The composer

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "3.0.*@dev",
        "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "2.3.*@dev",
        "sebastian/global-state": "1.0.*@dev",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.4.*@dev",
        "piece/stagehand-testrunner": "4.1.*@dev",
        "phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator": "2.0.*@dev"
    },
    "require": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.4.*@dev"
    }
}
```

As well as the latest version of makegood and everything now works as expected.
Works on Kepler and Luna